# IDA:Search for all the occurrence of certain opcode/register in current graph view

Tags: ida

I know that, after double clicking on a opcode or register, all the occurance of the  opcode/register in the graph view are highlighted.

Is there any easy way to just search for a opcode or register in the current graph view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nifty plugin that allows that - [localxrefs](https://github.com/devttys0/ida/tree/master/plugins/localxrefs).

It looks up all the references of the currently highlighted identifier in the current function, and prints out a list of those.